# Metric Space for Direction Cosine Matrix?

Tags: geometry

I work in the medical field. Sometime we receives MR images that have been acquired along the same direction, however when looking up the [direction cosine matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine#General_meaning), the values are slightly different (up to a certain precision). The scanner only stores the first 6 values of the matrix, the last 3 values are computed using a cross product from the first 2 vectors. Those two direction cosines define the [first row and the first column with respect to the patient](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.7.6.2.html#sect_C.7.6.2.1.1).

What is the correct metric space (equivalent to euclidean distance?) to compare two different direction cosine matrix ?

Typical example:

```py
import numpy as np
a1,b1=np.array([0.997704,0.0677201,6.10347E-5]),np.array([-0.0673549,0.992439,-0.102604])
a2,b2=np.array([0.997704,0.0677201,6.10347E-5]),np.array([-0.067355,0.992439,-0.102604])
a3,b3=np.array([0.997704,0.0677202,6.10347E-5]),np.array([-0.0673549,0.992439,-0.102604])
```

With a lot of hand waving, comparing the dot product of the normal give a sense of how close direction cosine matrix are:

```
>>> c1 = np.cross(a1,b1)
>>> c2 = np.cross(a2,b2)
>>> c3 = np.cross(a3,b3)
>>> np.dot(c1,c2)
0.9999987261098883
>>> np.dot(c2,c3)
0.9999987328817403
```

Comment: The function $d(x, y) = \arccos(x\cdot y)$ is a metric on the unit sphere, i.e. it's symmetric, positive-definite, and satisfies the triangle inequality. It's basically just the great circle distance between the two points. Is that what you mean by metric?

Comment: @DanielShapero, I think that your comment answer the question. Would you post it as such?

Comment: @DanielShapero I've updated my question, since it was not very clear I was talking about direction cosine matrix (not just direction cosines of a single vector).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing the suggestion by @DanielShapero (or at least how I understood it):

```
import numpy as np
def distance(a, b): # a & b contains each the first 6 values of direction cosine matrix
    ax, ay = a # ax is the first vector, ay is the second vector
    bx, by = b # bx is the first vector, by is the second vector
    az = np.cross(ax, ay) # ax × ay
    bz = np.cross(bx, by) # bx × by
    return np.arccos(np.dot(az, bz)) # d(x,y)=arccos(x⋅y)
```

Using my original example:

```
a1, b1 = np.array([0.997704, 0.0677201, 6.10347E-5]), np.array([-0.0673549, 0.992439, -0.102604])
a2, b2 = np.array([0.997704, 0.0677201, 6.10347E-5]), np.array([-0.067355, 0.992439, -0.102604])
a3, b3 = np.array([0.997704, 0.0677202, 6.10347E-5]), np.array([-0.0673549, 0.992439, -0.102604])
```

as well as:

```
a4, b4 = np.array([1, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 1, 0])
a5, b5 = np.array([0, 1, 0]), np.array([0, 0, 1])
a6, b6 = np.array([0, 0, 1]), np.array([1, 0, 0])
```

I can verify this give the expected result:

```
print(distance((a1, b1), (a2, b2)))
print(distance((a2, b2), (a3, b3)))
print(distance((a3, b3), (a1, b1)))

0.0015961769213946786
0.00159192872155101
0.0015961542345642986
```

Same for:

```
print(distance((a4, b4), (a5, b5)))
print(distance((a5, b5), (a6, b6)))
print(distance((a6, b6), (a4, b4)))

1.5707963267948966
1.5707963267948966
1.5707963267948966
```

---

Technically the expression based on arctan is the only one that is well-conditioned for [all angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Vector_version). So I ended up not using `arccos` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference direction I would suggest using the norm of the difference of each vector with the reference vector. Since the vectors are already normalized this works as a relative norm. Another option is to compute the angle between your direction and the reference one.

Comment: I do not have a reference direction...unless there is a way to compute the "mean" of multiple direction cosines...

Comment: You could compute the average of all your direction vectors.

Comment: my head hurts when I read "average" for direction vectors, could you briefly point me to an algorithm ?